# Python: Fastest Way to get no of duplicates of each uniqe row in a pandas DF full of duplicates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, duplicates

So I have a pandas dataframe full of repeats. I'm trying to count how many times each row has been repeated and put that into a column.

Here's my code - found it on stack overflow

```
def getUniqCounts2(dupDF ):
    countARR=[]
    uniqDF = getUniq(dupDF)
    for i in range( 0,len(uniqDF)):
        df2 = len(dupDF[(dupDF["variable1"]==uniqDF['variable1'][i]) &
         (dupDF["variable2"]==uniqDF['variable2'][i])])
        print(df2)
        countARR.append(df2)
    uniqDF['count'] = countARR
    return uniqDF
```

Someone did recommend the pivot table function, but the problem is that the resulting DF has a column that is only partially filled even though the input data frame had all columns filled.

Now I have a DF of 1.5M rows. I just want to get the unique rows, and the no of repetitions found per row. What would be the fastest way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have a DataFrame like named `df`, you can count the number of occurrences by simply using `groupby()` function like below:

```
counts = df.groupby(df.columns.tolist()).size().reset_index().rename(columns={0:'count'})
```

I guess this is much more efficient.